# Can't send POST from angular.js to express.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, rest, express, yeoman

I having problems to communicate between my angular.js APP and my express.js REST.

I'm using yeoman 1.0 with generator-angular 0.7.1.

I tried to use a middleware config for my `grunt serve` but i did not get it working.

Angular App (port: 9000):

```
angular.module('wboxApp')
  .controller('AdminCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, fbRef) {
    var ref = fbRef();
    var token = $routeParams.token;

    $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/box/token/get', {token: token}).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
```

Express API (port: 3000):

```
app.post('/box/token/get', function (req, res) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin || "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-Type,x-requested-with');

  var token = req.body.token;
  var tokenRef = ref.child('tokens').child(token);  

  tokenRef.once('value', function (data) {
    var fullToken = data.val();

    fullToken = fullToken + '.' + token;

    if (data.val()) {
      res.json({fullToken: fullToken});
    } else {
      res.json({fullToken: null});
    }
  });
});
```

Browser Error:

```
OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:3000/box/token/get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:3000/box/token/get. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the angular page was being served by server running on 127.0.0.1:9000. Cross origins policy disallows ajax requests from other domains. To get around it you can add express middleware which adds the headers for cross origin requests -

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,X-Requested-With');
    next();
});
```

Comment: i also added `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,OPTIONS');` and now it works.

Comment: I don't think that is needed in your case. 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' is only needed for preflighted requests. And yours is a post request which doesn't seem preflighted. What is the content-type of the request?

Comment: `application/json` but i think angular.post needs `OPTIONS`, whithout i get an error.

Comment: hmm... seems application/json requests are not the same as application/text, which is strange. and application/json requests are preflighted. Cool.

Comment: Sorry my fault: adding `Content-Type` to `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` gets it working.

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear, do not perform cross-origin requests!
There's an better way: grunt-connect-proxy - Issue requests to `9000` port and have your frontend server forward them to actual backend.

here's how to configure it in less than 3 minutes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21655532/1432478

Comment: I need CORS only for dev, so i think edit my Headers is the easier solution.

Comment: @cebor Is COR simpler? I would really questionnaire that. Furthermore,  it's not fully browser agnostic and you have to hardcode URLs. But as you wish